# How to find $ \iiint_{S} xyz\; dx dy dz$ for a given set $S$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Define the set 
>   $
> S:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^{3}:-3<z<1,x^{2}+y^{2}=36\}
> $
>   Find the integral 
>   $$
> \iiint_{S} xyz\; dx dy dz.
> $$

I am struggling with the equality $x^{2}+y^{2}=36$; I have only encountered inequalities until now: $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq36$ would be easy, as

$$
\int_{-3}^{1}\int_{0}^{6}\int_{-\sqrt{36-y^2}}^{\sqrt{36-y^2}}(xyz)\;dxdydz
$$

(I hope this is correct for the inequality case) But how can I treat equality $x^{2}+y^{2}=36$?

Comment: $S$ is the sheet that forms a cylinder. What are you struggling with? Its has volume zero. There is probably a typo.